# Meteor js requestPermissions not working

Tags: meteor, google-api, google-calendar-api

Meteor js requestPermissions not working. I want to access google calendar, access token not permission with google calendar. How I can get access google calendar.

Comment: Meteor.loginWithGoogle({
  requestPermissions: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks'],
  requestOfflineToken: true
 });

Comment: This is my sample code. Not working google scope

Comment: Please edit your topic when you want to add informations instead of posting comments.

Comment: Do you know any solution ?

Comment: Hi Bidhan Baral, this site can help you with many problems but in order to give people the chance to help it is important to create a "good" question. This means not only to know [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but also [how to format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) the question.

Comment: Okay. My question is , I'm not able to access google calendar with google api . I use meteor js google login feature. It's showing error  "message": "Insufficient Permission"

Comment: I know there are scope issues but not able to add google calendar scope in Meteor.loginWithGoogle() function

Comment: Like people already said, **edit your question** and stop posting things in comments.

Answer (score 1):

there are two things to consider. The right permission you need from google, and the API you use to access your data. You don't provide too many details so I don't know whether you need mobile (Cordova) too.

For your project, in Google Developer Console you need to enable the Calendar API. Once you do that, you have options to see what appId / authorization is relevant for your API so you add it to your Meteor Settings.

Then from the OAuth 2.0 scopes you need to select the exact scope you need (search for "calendar" for instance) and add that scope (the entire url) to your array of scopes.

Then you can do GET or POST with something like the native HTTP API of Meteor

example:

```
 let data = HTTP.call('GET', `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections?pageToken=${res.data.nextPageToken}&personFields=emailAddresses`,
              // let data = HTTP.call('GET', `https:https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{... your calendarId}  `,
                {
                  headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
                    Accept: 'application/json'
                  }
                },
                (err, res) => { handle these })
```

[image]